# ¿Como convertir un dato int a string en python?

Tags: python-3.x

Quiero convertir esta variable int a string.

```
number = int(input("type one number :"))
parseo = number.ToString();
```

para despues convertir esa variable "parseo" en una lista asi.

```
lista = list(parseo)
```

lo hago porque no puedo convertir un dato int a list directamente.

aqui el error.

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ToString'
```

no conozco la sintaxis para python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parece que vienes del mundo de Java en python debes utilizar la función `str()` como sigue:

```py
#Convertir a cadena
parseo = str(number)

#convertir cadena a entero
cadena= "1"
numero= int(cadena)
```

Es todo.

Puedes encontrar más acerca de conversiones en este enlace: [Conversiones en Python](https://unipython.com/casting-y-conversion-entre-tipo-de-datos/)

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: He agregado un enlace donde puedes encontrar más al respecto, saludos.